# Ext.Ajax.request not working

Tags: url, model-view-controller, extjs

[image: file structure image][image][![
this is the project structure I am using. On adding a local URL like this below code is not working. url:'data/showStudentInfo.html'][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB2WF.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB2WF.jpg)I am using Ext Js version 4.1.1
In my application , I am having a grid, which uses a store. 
On clicking "click me" button I want to redirect to the server, for test purpose I am using a basic google url,
But the class Ext.Ajax.Request is not working I think 
Please help , as I am new to Ext js, I am not aware of the mistake I am making.
I am trying this in notepad++, as well as in eclipse ide (indigo version).
both with same output, Ext.Ajax.Request part not working.
It will of great help if anyone have suggestion as if I want to send
Thanking in advance
Below is my html and js file

**practiseCellEditEx.js**

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.Ajax.',
    'Ext.grid.*'
]);

function getRandomDate() {
    var from = new Date(1900, 0, 1).getTime();
    var to = new Date().getTime();
    var date = new Date(from + Math.random() * (to - from));    
    return Ext.Date.clearTime(date);
}

function createFakeData(count) {
    var firstNames   = ['Ed', 'Tommy', 'Aaron', 'Abe'];
    var lastNames    = ['Spencer', 'Maintz', 'Conran', 'Elias'];            
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
        var dob = getRandomDate();           
        var firstNameId = Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length);
        var lastNameId  = Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length);
        var name        = Ext.String.format("{0} {1}", firstNames[firstNameId], lastNames[lastNameId]);
        data.push([name, dob]);
    }
    return data;
}

Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('Person',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['Name', 'dob']
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Person',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            data: createFakeData(10),
            reader: {type: 'array'}
        },
        sorters: [{
            direction:'ASC'
        }]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        plugins: [
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit : 1
            })
        ],
        columns: [
            {
                text: "Name", 
                width:120, 
                dataIndex: 'Name',
                editor : {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank:false
                }
            },
            {
                text: "DOB", 
                width: 120, 
                dataIndex: 'dob', 
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('M d, Y'),
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    format: 'M d, Y',
                    minValue: '01/01/1900',
                    maxValue: new Date()
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 30,
                sortable: false,
                menuDisabled: true,
                items: [{
                    icon: 'http://etf-prod-projects-1415177589.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/trac/docasu/export/2/trunk/client/extjs/shared/icons/fam/delete.gif',
                    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                       store.removeAt(rowIndex);
                    }
                }]
            }
        ],
        renderTo:'example-grid',
        width: 280,
        height: 280

    });  

    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
   // renderTo: Ext.getBody(),  
    renderTo:'myBtn',
    handler: getName
});

function getName (btn)  
   {
       alert("hello");
       var records = store.getAt(1);
       alert('the name at index 1 is:'+records.get('Name'));
       Ext.Ajax.request({
           url                 : 'https://www.google.co.in/'
                  });
   };
    /*
    function buttonClicked() {
    Ext.MessageBox.confirm( 'Delete this part ? :' );
}*/

});
```

**practiseCellEditEx.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>ExtJS Samples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="practiseCellEditEx.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h2> <b>Helllo , today's Date is 02.12.2015 </b></h2>
        <div id="example-grid"></div>
        <!--<button id="myBtn"></button>-->
        <div id="myBtn"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: please help me out , any suggestion will be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be simply the request going to google.com. In my browser it is blocked because it is a cross-origin request (an ajax request to another domain), see also here for further information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.

The same code with a request to a local URL works fine.

Comment: sorry daolaf , I wrong edited your answer , instead of editing my post. I wrongly posted the file structure in the edit section of your answered post. apologizing for that.

Comment: on adding a local url as url:'data/showStudentInfo.html' is not working for me, where data is a folder which contains a simple html page named:showStudentInfo.html